# Get Country Code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

how can I know the country code of the given number string? For example  **0917 8987 999** then the country code will be "**ph**". If you can provide me a resources, library or a sample code, It will be well appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is "0917 8987 999" a phone number ?

Comment: @Roy yep. a Philippines local number.

Comment: Philippine country code is +63 , so how 0917 8987 999 is a valid Philippine phone number  ?

Comment: Can you clarify the number type ; national , international or e164 ?

Comment: I want to generate the e164. But the displayed above is national number.

Answer (score 3):

For parsing country and validating international phone numbers You can use [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) .
Easy to Implement in `Swift` .

Implementation :

```
let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

        do {
            let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse("+33689017383")
            print(phoneNumber.countryCode)
            print(phoneNumberKit.mainCountry(forCode: phoneNumber.countryCode)!)
        }
        catch {
            print("Generic parser error")
        }
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample code on how do you get the country code using this lib? Already tried it but zero luck.

Comment: alright thanks, because I'm creating an app with different kinds of number. Others are from italy, ph, japan and etc. So I'm thinking if there's a way I can get country codes or format number internationally without knowing the region in PhoneNumberKit.

Comment: Any luck on this??

Comment: I think by default it will return "+1" as country code, any solution or work around for this?